# how to pass variable from twig path to the same controller?

Tags: symfony

In template i need to pass variable to controller when clicked link

```
{{ variable }}
<a href="{{ path('test',{ 'variable': 2}) }}">click</a>
```

.
How to do this?

```
/**
 * @Route("/test", defaults={"variable" = 1}, name="test")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function testAction($variable)
{
    return array('variable'=>$variable);
}
```

You will say i need placeholder in @Route `/test/{variable}`, then how to first time visit url `test`?

---

edit: this is silly question. I had some cache problem while testing this issue. The answear is obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define your `@Route` annotation like you mention:

```
/**
 * @Route("/test/{variable}", defaults={"variable" = 0}, name="test")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function testAction($variable)
{ 
    return array('variable'=>$variable);
}
```

Thanks to `defaults` option you can access your route with or without `variable`:

1. With:

   ```
   <a href="{{ path('test', {'variable': 2}) }}">click</a>
   ```

   This will generate url `/test/2` and your `$variable` will equal `2`
2. Without:

   ```
    <a href="{{ path('test') }}">click</a>
   ```

   This will generate url `/test` and your `$variable` will equal `0` (a value set in `defaults` option)

Comment: I swear. before asking the question i did what you write and get error something like: "no route for /test. You need to add variable". Today it's wroking pefect. Probably some cache problem while testing this issue yesterday. Thanks anyway, stupid question - good answear, Approve.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar, and @Tomasz, your answer helped me a lot. I my case I needed two variables.

Using the above example as a reference:

```
 * @Route("/test/{variable}/{var2}",
 *    defaults={"variable" = 0, "var2" = 0},
 *    name="test")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function testAction($variable, $var2)
{ 
    return array('variable'=>$variable, 'var2 => $var2);
}
```

Then in twig you can use:

```
<a href="{{ path('test', {'variable': 2, 'var2': 3}) }}">click</a>
```

which generates URL `/test/2/3`

In my case, I was using something more fancy, like an Entity:

```
<td><a href="{{ path('submitPetHasProgram',
    {'prog':stu.getTcProgram.getProgramId,
    'student':stu.getStuId}) }}">Select</a></td>
```

Hopefully this will help someone out in the future who is struggling for a solution to this type of problem.